# Cross-platform server application to communicate with Android/iOS on WiFi

Tags: java, android, python, c++, ios

I am working on an application where I need to establish a server on a Windows/Linux/Mac machine which will need to communicate to an Android/iOS device over an existing WiFi network.

I am just in the research phase for now, and though I can find answers for communicating between PC-Android, PC-iOS, Mac-iOS etcetera, I cannot find an answer using which I can do all of it.

The mobile application will be different for both the platforms, of-course, but the server application should ideally be the same, and should be cross-platform.
I should also mention that the server and the clients(mobile-apps) will maintain a 1:n relation, meaning that several Android/iOS devices will be communicating with the server at once.

1. I need advice on which language/library shall I use for the server which would let the it communicate to both the mobile platforms.
2. Advice on the libraries I should use for the mobile platforms will also be helpful, though it's not important until I complete the server.
3. I am just looking for links to helpful resources, though I will be very grateful if you share some code.

I shall also mention, I know Python/Java/C++ which I can use for the server, but you are open to suggest another language which may make the work easier.

EDIT: What I forgot to mention is that, this will be a local server, that is, it needs to communicate with these devices on a LAN (devices on the same wifi network).

Comment: All of these platforms support major common networking protocols.  What have you tried?

Comment: i have written one. We could discuss licensing terms if you like.

Comment: @MatthewRead I haven't tried anything as of now. I am looking at what I should try. I can't make my mind as to which technology to use. I have read about Java Sockets, and still researching on it.

Comment: I am sorry if the question is not a 'quality' question. It is my first time writing one, and I only just realised that questions can be down and upvoted too. I would take any suggestions on how to correct the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you Know Java for the server side you cab create an application that hosts a RestFull API running on a tomcat server that you call with a local address (such as http://ip_adress:port/appname)

Tomcat can run on Windows, Linux or Mac.

If you need more informations just ask

Comment: Can this not be achieved without bringing in web based technologies like tomcat? I was reading about Java Sockets. How viable is that option?

Comment: You can code all the communication layer and protocol on your own if you want but do you think that you'll do better than worldwide teams that are  working on the subject since years ?

Comment: Of Course not. Seems like I came here with way to little research that I should have. Thank you for the suggestion, I'll start reading. I'll come back for any clarifications.

Comment: Not at all, everyday people are calling web server over local network, there are several ways depending on how admins have configured it.